# Looking for a CMS that integrates with a custom DB

Tags: content-management-system, headless-cms, jamstack

I'm having an issue with a project I'm working on.

I have an app with its own db that contains the users and their credentials.
I want to have a headless CMS that manages some blogs to avoid writing one of my own, but I can't seem to find a CMS that doesn't have its own separate users system.

So my question is whether there is a CMS that I can integrate with to make it see my users in my database? or should I make my own and forget about integrating with a third-party?

Thank you

Comment: Have you looked into Strapi cms? https://strapi.io/documentation/3.0.0-alpha.x/guides/databases.html#mongodb-installation

Comment: I think Strapi or Ghost can match